# Assign an activity from ecoinvent to a variable and access the activity's properties

Tags: brightway

I would like to retrieve the names (and possibly additional information) of all inputs and outputs of an activity. In my understanding, this would allow me to e.g. see of which individual inputs electricity production mixes are comprised of.

First, I select a database via `ecoinvent_db = bw.Database('ecoinvent 3.7.1_cutoff')` and search for activities which could be of relevance for my objective.

Input:

```py
ecoinvent_db.search('electricity production mix')
```

Output:

```py
['electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, CH, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, AU, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, TZ, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, TH, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, MT, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, RU, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, PE, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, IR, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, MX, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, JP, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, CL, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, CY, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, MY, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, UA, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, IS, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, TW, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, KR, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, SA, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, ID, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, ZA, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, CA-YK, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, CA-ON, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, CA-PE, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, CA-NF, None),
 'electricity, high voltage, production mix' (kilowatt hour, CA-NS, None)]
```

Next, I would like to assign one of these activities to a variable (I can do this in a loop later on). In one of the example notebooks, an activity is assigned to a variable via `database.get()`. However in the example given in the notebook, the name of the activity is simply a string. In case of ecoinvent, the names of the activities are not unique and `db.search(str)` returns the given activities as `'activity_name' (unit, region, None)'`.

If I use `ecoinvent_db.get()` and then one of the outputs above in brackets I receive an `ActivityDatasetDoesNotExist` error.

I can select a random activity and print the names via:

```py
activity = bw.Database("ecoinvent 3.7.1_cutoff").random()

for exchange in activity.exchanges():
    print(exchange)
```

However, `activity_exchanges = list(activity.exchanges())` will only yield the following.

[image]

How can I assign an activity from ecoinvent to a variable and access or add its properties (e.g. name, exchanges, etc.) to a list or dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say the name you have assigned to ecoinvent is

```
MY_DB_NAME == 'ecoinvent 3.7.1_cutoff'
```

I'd suggest you loop through the activities to find what you want instead of using search. For example this returns a activity object:

```py
elec_example = next(act for act in bw2data.Database(MY_DB_NAME) if act['name'] == 'electricity, high voltage, production mix')
```

picking one of the values of your list would also work.

The key of the activity is a tuple with the name of the database and a unique (within the database) code. You can use the `get_activity` function with the key of the activity or use `get` method of the database to retrieve the activity too (if you know the key or the code).

```py
assert bw2data.get_activity(elec_example.key) == elec_example
assert bw2data.Database(MY_DB_NAME).get(elec_example['code']) == elec_example
```

You can access the different data associated with the activity object. e.g. `elec_example['name']`

The method .exchanges() returns an iterable. You could have a list of the exchanges simply with `list(elec_example.exchanges())` or iterate over the exchanges with a for loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! With your help I managed to access activities via `bw2data.get()`. I now use `bw2data.get_activity(('ecoinvent 3.7.1_cutoff',elec_example['code']))` which for me, as a Python-layman, appears "easier" ;-) 
Anyway how can I access the exchanges of that activity? I am not very familiar with the correct terminology but apparently `elec_example` can be used with `elec_example.exchanges()` but this only returns `<bw2data.backends.peewee.proxies.Exchanges at 0x21bf531a7c8>`. What I would like to retrieve is a list/dataframe with the exchanges.

Comment: Ah sorry. I just noticed you gave that answer as well! ... `list(elec_example.exchanges())` Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I edited the response to answer your comment.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot!! I look forward to getting more familiar with Brightway ...